# Connecting to server through ipaddress

Tags: android

I want to connect to server through ipaddress and then i want to display all files and folders in listview.

I am using apache httpclient but when i entered ipaddress in url then it is getting malformexception.

I wanted to know how to connect to server through ipaddress and then list all files and folders in listview. I have shown all files and folders of sdcard in listview.

Any tutorial will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible only if your IP address is not a SHARED one. Make your your hosting is not shared with anyone else. U gotta gave unique IP address for your hosting site!!